# How can I store a range of cells to an array?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

If I have a list of data in cells A1:A150 (but the amount can vary), is there a way to push that into an array without looking at each cell individually to determine if it is empty? I exceed my execution time by doing this and I need a faster way to store the data and stop when it hits an empty cell.

Below is how I currently do it:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 500; i++) {
  if(datasheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue() == ""){
   break;   
  }

  else{
     addedlist_old.push(datasheet.getRange("A" + i).getValue())
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're using only one column, I'd suggest:

```
  // my2DArrayFromRng = sh.getRange("A2:A10").getValues();
  var my2DArrayFromRng = [["A2"],["A3"],["A4"],["A5"],[],[],["A8"],["A9"],[]];
  var a = my2DArrayFromRng.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
```

The methods **.join()** and **.split(',')** together convert the 2D array to a plain array (["A2","A3","A4","A5",,,"A8","A9",]).
Then the method **.filter(Boolean)** strips the empty elements. The code above returns [A2, A3, A4, A5, A8, A9].

Comment: This was helpful in resolving my problem with creating an HTML options list from a sheets column

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues(); //getRange(starting Row, starting column, number of rows, number of columns)

    for(var i=0;i<(lastRow-1);i++)
    {
      Logger.log(data[0][i]);
    }
```

the variable **data** stores all the cells of column A.

Cell A1 is stored in data[0][0], cell A2 is stored in data[0][1], cell A3 is stored in data[0][2] and so on.

The **getRange(starting Row, starting column, number of rows, number of columns)** is a batch operation so it is much faster when you have a large dataset.

Comment: What if I have data in other cells? Wouldn't lastRow var be different hen? i dont see anything that explicitly refers to column a.

Comment: In your question you have explicitly mentioned A1:A150 (which is only Column A). Also, the code that you initially tried will work only for column A.

Comment: in the for loop in the code that i shared with you...you can add the if condition that you've previously used in your code and then push the values that you require to a variable.

Comment: To get to a solution quickly...i would suggest you share a sample data and then clarify what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: I want to grab all the data in a column I specify and then for each cell in that column, put it into a variable that is an array.

Comment: so what you are asking is possible using the code i shared. All you have to do is change the starting column index in the **getRange** method. For column A...column index is 1, for B it is 2 and so on.

If you want all data of column **J** then the this line will work :

`var data = sheet.getRange(1, 10, lastRow, 1);`

If you notice only the second parameter changes.

Comment: I ran what you have and when I tried to output the "data" var into a cell to see what was there, all I got was the word ""Range"

Comment: My bad.... `var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues();`

This is what will work.

Comment: This seems to work, but the issue now is that I take 2 arrays like this and compare them for differences, and the code you have returns a giant array with each cell inside its own array. Ex: [[stuff], [stuff2], [stuff3]] - I need each data piece to not be in its own array.

Comment: The reason for each cell being inside its own array is that it represents the entire row.

if you can manage to transpose your data inside the spreadsheet then your problem might get solved.

or what you can do is store **data[0]** in any variable...say for example **var columnData** and then in the for loop you can use **columnData[i]** instead of having to use **data[0][i]**

Comment: @SuyashGandhi - could you update your answer to incorporate the .getValues() portion? It could save future seekers time and anguish. Thanks!

Comment: @somewhatsapient thanks for bringing it to my notice. I've made the change and incorporated the .getValues() method in the code. Thanks again for pointing it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: I wonder if Google has made a change recently.  Using one column of data with my getRange, I now get a 1-dimensional array instead of 2.  I used to get 2, so it threw me when my results from Logger.log(data[0][i]) were all null.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have empty cells in between it's actually pretty easy.

```
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var array = sheet.getRange('A1:A' + lastRow).getValues();
```

If you need to weed out empty entries after that, you can use a for statement, or to be faster, filter like an earlier answer shows.

```
var filteredArray = array.filter(function(n){ return n != '' });
```

The main difference between this answer and the one posted earlier that I mentioned is that getValues() will give you an array.

I've tested this and it works in google apps script, and it does not time out when I use the array, or even when I put in large amounts of data (I tested it with an array that has about 20-50 characters per entry and about 500 entries). Just make sure to define the var sheet or put in your own variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

It will allow you to select any column on the sheet.

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {

  ui.createMenu('Sheet Functions')
 .addItem('Get values from column', 'getVals')
 .addToUi();    
 }

function getVals() {
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var getColumnLetter = ui.prompt('Select column..' , 'Enter the letter of the target column..', ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(getColumnLetter.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) { 
  return } else {
  getColumnLetter = getColumnLetter.getResponseText().toUpperCase();
  }

var columnNo = getColumnLetter.charCodeAt(0) - 64;

try { var data = sheet.getRange(1, columnNo, sheet.getMaxRows()).getValues().filter(String); } catch (e) { ui.alert('Invalid input please try again.', ui.ButtonSet.OK); return;}

/*
*
* Do what ever you need to do down here
*
*/
}
```