# Loop through cell range and clean range

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am working with Google Sheets and trying to figure out a script that will loop through a predefined range, Sheet name "Settings" Range (A2:A25) and clean the contents of the range ("K3:N25") for each sheet in the settings range.

I know in excel I could write the code in a for each statement, however, I am new to Javascript and am unsure how to write the same statement. I already have a code that will clean the contents of a specified range on a specified sheet but I want to loop through 10 - 15 sheets using a list.

```
function clearRange(){
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Anna");
  sheet.getRange("K3:N25").clearContent();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sheets = ["Anna", "John"];

function clearRange(sheets, range){
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) { // iterate all sheets
     var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
     sheet.getRange(range).clearContent();
  }
}

clearRange(sheets, "K3:N25")
```

Comment: Is there anyway to have the 'var sheets =' portion be a range from another sheet? My goal is to have a dynamic list on a sheet that will be adaptable so to speak. Being able to change the list in one place vs multiple places would be preferred.

Comment: @KevinTuri yes, you can do something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016026/store-range-of-cells-to-array

Comment: I also copied your code and made no changes to it, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 4, file "Code")"

Comment: @KevinTuri that means sheets is undefined, which means you are either calling clearRange without parameters or the parameter you are sending is undefined

Comment: I'm just a little confused as in I'm using the code that you supplied based on the parameters that I supplied and its not working. I will try else where. Thanks for your attempted assistance.

Comment: @KevinTuri show your complete code, it all depends on how you are calling clearRange function